# End of stream iterator is configurable?

Tags: c++, std, istream-iterator

Please consider the code below:

```
vector<__int64> vNumbers;   
copy(istream_iterator<__int64>(cin), istream_iterator<__int64>(), back_inserter(vNumbers));
```

If I'll enter `1 23 45` and press `Enter` the vector will be filled with 45, 23, 1, numbers.
Now a simple question. How can I change the code so that if I press `Enter` and enter new numbers the numbers were added to the vector too? In other words how to configure end of stream iterator?

Comment: How will you signify the end of stream in this case?

Comment: This is another and a good question?

Comment: Well if you want to configure the output stream, you'll have to denote some other way of dealing with the end of stream, otherwise it'll just keep gobbling up numbers and never stop. If you don't want <enter> to signify the end stream, what should?

Comment: For example `x` or `end` or something which makes sense.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It doesn't work like you say it does, at least not on my terminal. I need to enter Ctrl+Z before it stops reading.

Comment: There are zillions of options. End-of-file condition, blank line, any non-number, some particular token, anything. The question stands. How to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the stream reads as far as it can without blocking again. As soon as you press `[Enter]`, stdin gets flushed by the operating system (in some cases, not in all cases). The stream reads until EOF or until there is nothing to be read anymore. This is what occurs on every flush (bunch of new data available at once).

That's why different people observe different behaviour. As soon as you pipe a file into the stream, it will have the whole file available at once and only stop at the end of the file. The newlines is just whitespace to the stream, alike spaces and tab.

You cannot solve this problem without controlling the input at a lower level.